# logging - format with extra dict with optional elements

Tags: python, logging

I want to achieve a result like this:

```
# code
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s: %(sublevel) %(message)s', 
                    level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug("abc", extra={'sublevel':2})
logging.debug("def", extra={'sublevel':1}) 
logging.debug("ghi")
```

---

```
# output
DEBUG:        abc
DEBUG:    abc
DEBUG:abc
```

The problem is then I do not define in extra dict the sublevel item and I do not know how to change numeric value of `sublevel` to `(sublevel*4)*' '`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom `Formatter` subclass which uses the `sublevel` value to format the output string with the appropriate number of spaces, or use `extra={'prefix': ' ' * sublevel}` and use `"%(levelname)s: %(prefix)s %(message)s"` in the format string with a plain `Formatter`.